# wpa_supplicant ignore some networks

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am using wpa_supplicant and would like to add a rule so that my machine connects to any open network.
I can do this with:

```
network={
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Now I would like to blacklist some wireless networks. Is that possible? I need to do this as my computer is also a router which sends out an open network.

How can I ignore this ssid:

```
network={
    ssid="router"
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

---

Easiest solution for you would be for your AP to ban the MAC address of your client.

That, or just stop trying to connect to every open BSS network out there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `wpa_supplicant` to connect to wireless networks. I believe you should always *whitelist* and never *blacklist*, i.e. that you should use explicit configuration for unauthenticated networks as well as for authenticated ones. Otherwise you never know where you are connecting and you will often end up with defunct conectivity.

There are tools that can make that easier for you like NetworkManager with its GUI or CLI frontend to connect to new networks. There are a couple of other tools for the same purpose. With those tools, the first access to a new SSID is always explicit, while the second and next is automatic for networks you already successfully connected to.

The whole point of using `wpa_supplicant` directly is to have full control your wireless configuration. Connecting to random SSIDs is not in line with that.